# How to Create new session with given session id in java

Tags: java, session, websphere, session-cookies, load-balancing

we have our application deployed on a multi cluster environment running with load balancer on WebSphere 8.5.

Session Affinity is enabled on WebSphere.

In our application, once the session expires , a new session is created with new SessionID but to make session affinity work SessionID in request header should be same as that of the initial request made to load balancer.

**what I want to achieve ?**

once session is expired a call to request.getSession(); creates a new session with new SessionID.

I have stored SessionID of old session and now i want to update this new Session with old SessionID.

Please see below how session is updated in request header cookie and cloneID remains the same.

[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If the session expired, there is no point of creating session with same ID, since that session and all the data is already gone (expired).

Comment: If I create a new session and update it's sessionId with old session's sessionId (if there is at all a way), wouldn't it work ?

Internally when it will search for old SessionId will it not pass on the new session ?

Comment: Rahul, API doesn't allow to update session ID, it is read only. I still doesn't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Session Management custom property, HttpSessionIdReuse, that allows you to use the incoming *id* even if a new underlying session is needed.  Check the KC for full details and give it a try.